# FFmpeg percentage progress in javascript

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

I use javascript, Vue 3 and FFmpeg version:

```
"@ffmpeg/core": "^0.11.0",
"@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.11.6",
```

I have a function that cuts videos based on times entered by the user:

```
async videoTrim() {
  this.ffmpeg.FS("writeFile", "video.mp4", await fetchFile(videoData.source));

  await this.ffmpeg.run(
    "-ss", startTime,
    "-i", "video.mp4",
    "-to", endTime,
    "-crf", "23",
    "-c:v", "copy",
    "-c:a", "copy",
    "-reset_timestamps", "1",
    "-avoid_negative_ts", "1",
    "videoNew.mp4",
  )

  return this.ffmpeg.FS("readFile", "videoNew.mp4");
}
```

**PROBLEM**:
I need to find out the **percentage progress** during video trimming so that I can give the user information about how long the trimming will take
(If you have any comments or suggestions for improving the function `this.ffmpeg.run`, please let me know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for getting the percentage progress from FFmpeg tasks, the FFmpeg library itself doesn't provide a native way to get the current progress. However, you can usually utilize the log output from FFmpeg to determine the progress of tasks.

But with `@ffmpeg/ffmpeg`, you can set up progress tracking by adding an event listener for the 'message' event on the worker instance.

First, you'll need to get access to the FFmpeg worker instance.

After that, you can add an event listener for the 'message' event to the worker.

Based on the logs that FFmpeg outputs, you can extract the current frame or time and calculate the percentage progress.

I revised your code and here's a rough idea of how this can be implemented:

```js
// Assuming you have an instance of FFmpeg
const { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } = FFmpeg;

const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({
  log: true,
});

ffmpeg.setProgress(({ ratio }) => {
  console.log(`Percentage: ${Math.round(ratio * 100)}%`);
});

async function videoTrim(videoData, startTime, endTime) {
  await ffmpeg.load();
  ffmpeg.FS("writeFile", "video.mp4", await fetchFile(videoData.source));

  await ffmpeg.run(
    "-ss", startTime,
    "-i", "video.mp4",
    "-to", endTime,
    "-crf", "23",
    "-c:v", "copy",
    "-c:a", "copy",
    "-reset_timestamps", "1",
    "-avoid_negative_ts", "1",
    "videoNew.mp4",
  );

  return ffmpeg.FS("readFile", "videoNew.mp4");
}
```

the `setProgress` method and progress event usage is just a rough example and might need adjustments based on your setup and needs.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I found one more solution

this.ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({
    log: false,
    progress(duration) {
        console.log('progress', duration);
    }
});